# Boltzmann sampling for containers/dependent polynomials?

Tags: co.combinatorics, lo.logic, type-theory, dependent-type, sampling

I’d like to randomly sample from dependently-typed data structures.

Has anyone looked at extending [Boltzmann sampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boltzmann_sampler) to [containers](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0304397505003373) or [dependent polynomials](https://www.irif.fr/%7Emellies/mpri/mpri-ens/articles/gambino-hyland-polynomial-functors.pdf)?

Comment: What exactly do you want to sample, what syntax? (In any case, I doubt this has been done.)

Comment: I'd like to randomly generate well-formed elements of dependently-typed inductive datatypes (eg, for quickcheck-style property-based testing).